# TreeView selectionChanged called twice when focus to other control

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

When focus is set to other control in TreeView SelectionChanged, it get called again and also Parent node of TreeView get selected. Can any one help in this and also it reproduce only when focus is used.

```
<TabControl x:Name="tab">
    <TabItem x:Name="tab1" Header="Item1"/>
    <TabItem x:Name="tab2" Header="Item2"/>
</TabControl>
<TreeView SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Header">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item1"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item2"/>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

This is simple XAML code

```
private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    tab2.Focus();
    //tab.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Here I changed the focus.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on one of the subitems, it first selects the header, which fires off your event which in turn, puts the focus back on the tab and never actually finishes selecting the subitem. Unless you have a specific reason to call "Focus()", I wouldn't recommend it in this scenario. What I think you mean to do is set the "IsSelected" property to true on the tab control.

If you change your code behind to the following, your example will work as I think you intend:

```
private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            tab2.IsSelected = true;
        }
```

***If for some reason, you think it's absolutely necessary to set the focus on the tab control (which, at this point, you haven't explained why you're doing it), you might want to set the "Focusable" property to false on the Header. This way, the Header doesn't get selected, and thus, never calls the SelectedItemChanged event, like so:***

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <StackPanel>
            <TabControl x:Name="tab">
                <TabItem x:Name="tab1" Header="Item1"/>
                <TabItem x:Name="tab2" Header="Item2"/>
            </TabControl>
            <TreeView SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Header" Focusable="False">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Item1"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Item2"/>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeView>
        </StackPanel>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

By the way, I put your stuff in a StackPanel so I could actually see the Tab getting changed.

Comment: Thanks Ryan... In my case i need to set focus to TabItem.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit late but I came accross the same issue. This is how I solved it:

Disabling the re-enabling the treeview prevent it from firing SelectedChanged when focus is lost.

```
private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    TreeView.IsEnabled = false;

    tab2.Focus();
    //tab.SelectedIndex = 1;

    TreeView.IsEnabled = true;
}
```